# How can I return True if same character is found in two lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, duplicates

I need to write a function that accepts two lists and returns True if the same character is found in both lists.
for example, if the lists are **L1 = ['v', 'a', 'b', 'c']** and **L2 = ['j', 'k', 'v']**, it should return *True* because 'v' is in both lists. This is what I have, but I assume it just evaluates the very first character and returns a bool based on that. How can I make it so that it goes through every character and runs like the example I wrote above?

````
def contains_duplicates(L1, L2):
  for i in L1:
    if i in L1 and i in L2:
      return True
    else: return False```
````

Comment: Simpler (and often faster) if inputs are hashable: `return not set(L1).isdisjoint(L2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first element of `L1` is not in `L2`,you should check the nexe element of `L1` instead of `return`

```
def contains_duplicates(L1, L2):
  for i in L1:
    if i in L2:
      return True
  return False
```